# How can I generate MD5 hash for an Element in XML

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hash, md5

How can I generate MD5 hash for Place Element in XML. I want to calculate all the attributes and values in Place Element.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-9"?>
<?hash 73533cd0fa219185648ff9554b065bd3?>
<Place Code="1111" Date="2016-06-18 11:28:58">
  <User Name="NAME" Number="1"/>
</Place>
```

//Place Element

```
        Element results = doc.createElement("Place");
        doc.appendChild(results);

        results.setAttribute("Code", "1111");
        results.setAttribute("Date", sdt);

        while((rs!=null) && (rs.next())) {

            Element row = doc.createElement("User");
            results.appendChild(row);

            // Attributes
            Attr xnumber = doc.createAttribute("Number");
            xnumber.setValue(rs.getString("number_db"));
            row.setAttributeNode(xnumber);

            Attr xname = doc.createAttribute("Name");
            xname.setValue(rs.getString("name_db"));
            row.setAttributeNode(xname);
    }
```

**EDIT:** MD5 code..

```
    String result = null;
    char hexDigits[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
            '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(source);
    //The result should be one 128 integer
    byte temp[] = md.digest();
    char str[] = new char[16 * 2];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        byte byte0 = temp[i];
        str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf];
        str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 & 0xf];
    }
    result = new String(str);
```

I use `source = rs.getBytes("name_db");` for attributes and values but hash code not changing. What must I do?

Comment: results.ToString();

Comment: String s = results.toString(); .. digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); digest.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length()); System.out.println("MD5: "+new BigInteger(1,digest.digest()).toString(16)); I think this is wrong. It doesn't give me different code when I add an user to mysql.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was XML linq.   You have straight XML so use either results.OuterXml  (or InnerXml).

Comment: I could'nt find any information about OuterXml or InnerXml for java